# Android - Common style resources when using library projects?

Tags: android, xml, library-project

I am making some shared libs that are common to several projects i am doing. Problem is that when it comes to XML, the library project's XML is not included in the main project. At the moment i am doing everything programmatically which is obviously not ideal.

Is there a way of doing this (other than pasting it manually every time)

Bearing in mind other members of the team have to use this "framework" too so i want it really to be a case of just reference it and use it without too much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

You can access xml files in your libs as long as you import the lib as a "library project" (and not as a jar). Also make sure that all the resources in the lib have a unique name and do not conflict with a resource name in your project.
For more information see also [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html)

Comment: It is not critical to define the same resource ID as in the library project. As stated in the document you linked: `In cases where a resource ID is defined in both the application and the library, the tools ensure that the resource declared in the application gets priority and that the resource in the library project is not compiled into the application .apk. This gives your application the flexibility to either use or redefine any resource behaviors or values that are defined in any library.`

Comment: @Idolon Yes you are right, but what if you would like to use the library resource instead of your own resource. If you use the same resource ID for both you basically "overwrite" the library resource.

Comment: Yes, correct. As stated in the citation above: "This gives your application the flexibility to either use or redefine any resource behaviors or values that are defined in any library" :-)

Comment: I find it is inconvenient if the library's resources have the same package name as the library's source (which is the default).  Then an import com.lib.*; pulls in the library's resource so then you have to specify all your resources full path explicitly or else they are ambiguous.

Comment: NOT WORK ANYMORE